# SQL Server 2012 Express - silent installation.

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012, silent

I am failing to silently install SQL Server 2012 Express (Advanced). I followed the guidance and this is my command:

```
Setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,Tools /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="MyDomain\Coduy" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="w1llywonka" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="MyDomain\Coduy" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Installation runs and after a short while I can see that SQL Server added setup process to the start menu:

[image]

I need to silently install SQL Server and Server Management Studio.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  Have you checked in Services?  The first link I pulled up suggested that management studio is SSMS rather than tools.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Comment: There is no error message. Installation ends with SQL Server Installation Center created in Start menu. As per your link suggestion... if you scroll down the page you will see that Tools is a parent feature parametr that is meant to install SSMS and couple of other add-ons.

Comment: What does the log say under setup bootstrap?

Comment: @SeanGallardy. You were on the right track: I checked the log and I was missing NetFramework 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed by:

> @SeanGallardy

I checked the logs and it turned out that NetFramework 3.5 was missing and that stopped the process of installation go to further. NetFramework 3.5 is not enabled by default on Windows 8 and above.